# Continue a if statement in C++

Tags: c++, continue

To reduce indentation in my code I want to skip a if statement if a condition is met.
Let this be the following code:

```cpp
if (foo()) {
    if (bar()) if_continue;        // continue the code and dont execute buz()

    buz();
}
...¹
```

The normal `continue` does not work.
And I also cant use `return` because code at [¹] should still be executed.

I also want to avoid a solution like this, because this would result in unwanted indentation:

```cpp
if (foo()) {
    if (!bar()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this possible in C++?

Comment: What's wrong with `if(foo() && !bar())`?

Comment: Nothing to say about this question in particular but the best way to reduce indentation is to split your code into separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the true-branch statement by a call to a lambda function from which you return, if you want something like that:

```
  if (foo()) [](){
      if (bar()) {
        return;
      }
      buz();
    }();
```

But personally I find this

```
if (foo()) {
    if (!bar()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

a lot more readable.

Comment: Arguably the lambda should be wrapped in `{}` or at least started on a separate lines yielding no benefit for intendation..